# How to make this code more compact and readable?

Tags: haskell, coding-style

I am a Java programmer who learns Haskell.
I've written a small program that searches files for words with a particular suffix.

I'd like to read your criticism.
What would you suggest to make this code more compact and readable?

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Data.String.Utils
import Data.List
import Data.Char
import System.Directory
import System.FilePath
import System.IO
import System.IO.HVFS.Utils
import Text.Regex

alphaWords :: String -> [String]
alphaWords = words . map (\c -> if isAlpha c then c else ' ') -- by ephemient
-- was:
-- words2 s =  case dropWhile isSpace2 s of
--     "" -> []
--     ss -> w : words2 sss
--         where (w, sss) = break isSpace2 ss
--     where isSpace2 = not . isAlpha

findFiles :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
findFiles path = do
    cur_path <- getCurrentDirectory
    files <- recurseDir SystemFS $ normalise $ combine cur_path path
    filterM doesFileExist files

wordsWithSuffix :: String -> String -> [String]
wordsWithSuffix suffix text =
    let tokens = (nub . alphaWords) text
        endswithIgnoringCase = endswith suffix . map toLower
    in filter endswithIgnoringCase tokens

searchWords :: String -> String -> [String] -> IO [String]
searchWords suffix path exts = do
    let isSearchable = (`elem` exts) . takeExtension -- by yairchu
    --was let isSearchable s = takeExtension s `elem` exts

    --files <- filterM (fmap isSearchable) $ findFiles path -- by ephemient (compile error)
    files <- liftM (filter isSearchable) $ findFiles path

    wordsPerFile <- forM files $ fmap (wordsWithSuffix suffix) . readFile -- by ephemient
    -- was: wordsPerFile <- forM files (\x -> liftM (wordsWithSuffix suffix) (readFile x))

    return . sort . nub $ concat wordsPerFile -- by ephemient
    -- was: return $ (sort . nub . concat) wordsPerFile

main = do
    words <- searchWords "tick" "/path/to/src" [".as", ".java", ".mxml"]
    print $ length words
    putStrLn $ unlines words
```

**UPDATE:** I've fixed 2 verbose spots found using "hlint", thanks @yairchu
**UPDATE 2:** More fixes. Thanks @ephemient
**UPDATE 3:** One little fix. Thanks @yairchu, can't use all of your code - too hard for a Java dev's mind

Comment: Try writing an implementation and then asking for help optimising rather than trying to get others to do it for you. Otherwise I'd suggest hiring a Haskell programmer to develop this for you.

Comment: No, it is not. See my code bellow.

Comment: definitely sounds like something I was once set as homework

Comment: You aren't asking for anything.  "Why doesn't this work as I expect?" or "How can I make this better?" are possible questions (though over-general; a good question is one that can be definitively answered).  What do you really want?  We can't read your mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't `import System.FilePath.Posix` if you don't need to.  `System.FilePath` exports `System.FilePath.Posix` or `System.FilePath.Windows` according to the platform you're compiling on.

Your `words2` implementation is fine, but lacks any explanation as to *why* it does what it does.  This is more self-explanatory, and the efficiency difference is not significant.

```
alphaWords = words . map (\c -> if isAlpha c then c else ' ')
```

Little improvements in `searchWords`:

```
-    wordsPerFile <- forM files (\x ->
-        liftM (wordsWithSuffix suffix) (readFile x))
+    wordsPerFile <- forM files $ fmap (wordsWithSuffix suffix) . readFile
-    return $ (sort . nub . concat) wordsPerFile
+    return . sort . nub $ concat wordsPerFile
```

Type annotations inside `let` constructs are not common unless the typechecker really needs assistance... though if I were paying attention to them I wouldn't have made my earlier mistake of trying to move `isSearchable` :)

Also, in `main`, I would change this:

```
-    putStrLn $ unlines words
+    mapM_ putStrLn words
```

I'm not familiar with the modules exposed by MissingH; is `System.IO.HVFS.Utils.recurseDir` lazy?  If not, adding [`System.IO.Unsafe.unsafeInterleaveIO`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v%3AunsafeInterleaveIO) may help with memory consumption when traversing a large directory tree.

Comment: Problem here: "files <- filterM isSearchable $ findFiles path"
the type is "filterM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]"
but expected to be "filterM :: (Monad m) => (a -> Bool) -> m [a] -> m [a]"

Comment: Ah, I didn't compile-test it.  It would need to be `filterM (fmap isSearchable)`, which makes it as preferable.

Comment: Edited to "files <- filterM (fmap isSearchable) $ findFiles path" -- got "Couldn't match expected type `[m FilePath]' against inferred type `IO [FilePath]'"

Comment: Argh.  I typed that up real quick before dinner -- now that I've got an interpreter in front of me, I see what you're trying to do there... I'll fix my post.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, start by asking [hlint](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/).

It would give you a few useful suggestions and lessons, like:

```
homework.hs:46:1: Error: Use print
Found:
  putStrLn $ show $ length words
Why not:
  print (length words)
```

so we see that `print = putStrLn . show`

etc

Comment: hlint rocks. Thanks. How would you simplify "searchWords" function?

Answer (score 2):

I don't like variable names.

Hence here's a shorter `searchWords`:

```
searchWords :: String -> String -> [String] -> IO [String]
searchWords suffix path exts =
  fmap (sort . nub . concatMap (wordsWithSuffix suffix)) .
  mapM readFile . filter ((`elem` exts) . takeExtension)
  =<< findFiles path
```

Comment: Shorter, yes; more readable, depends on the reader :-D  Looks fine to me, anyhow.  (Digression: why use `Control.Monad.liftM` when `Prelude.fmap` will do?)

Comment: @ephemient: that's a nasty habit. from writing generic code for Monads. since Monad doesn't imply Functor automatically..

Comment: It's more a nasty wart in Haskell than a nasty habit. Monad really should imply both Applicative and Functor.